# Building projects in VS2019, which is fastest - single core or multi core cpu?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Using Visual Studio 2019...

I have som huge projects and it takes a long time to build them.

I want to buy a new CPU, should I go with a fast single core CPU (like the Intel Core i9-11900K) or should I chose a fast multicore CPU (like AMD Threadripper 3960X)?

Does VS2019 take advantage of multicore CPU when building/runinning projects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wished, VS IDE does support [multi-core build process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/using-multiple-processors-to-build-projects?view=vs-2019).

VS first will get a basic performance evaluation based on your current CPU hardware. Then, you should open the switch under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Projects and Solutions**-->**Build and Run**-->and you will see **maximum number of parallel project builds**.

Set the number of build process based on your CPU performance.

**Obviously**, it is better to use multi-core build.

**Note**: value `1` means single-core and you should expand the value to enable multi-core build.

**If** you build c++ projects, there is another second option under  **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Projects and Solutions**-->**VC++ Project Settings**-->**Maximum concurrent c++ compilation**.

In this suitation, value `0` means all CPU will be used.